# Trigger a button click event without pressing the button (Winforms)

Tags: winforms, events, eventtrigger

I have 2 `WinForm` forms. One called **mainForm**, and another **mappingForm**.
On **mainForm** I have a button called **show_mappingForm**.
On **mappingForm** I have a button called **show_Diagram**.

I need to accomplish the following: by pressing **show_mappingForm** to show the form and rise the event of showing the diagram (event rised by clicking **show_Diagram**). I want to simulate this pressing in order to show the diagram imediatelly together with second form.
I have been searching on the internet something like this: trigger button click event but ended with anything clear.

I have tryed to call the event of showing the diagram inside of the method of showing the second form.

```
MainForm.cs:

 private void button_show_mappingForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ........
     mappingForm.ShowDialog();
     mappingForm.showDiagramButton_Click(sender, e);
 }
```

but this thing didn't work.

Appreciate each tiny advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to invoke the button's method `PerformClick()` as follows

```
private void button_show_mappingForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ........
    mappingForm.ShowDialog();
    show_Diagram.PerformClick();
}
```

Assuming the button's event you're trying to launch is that `show_Diagram`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day